# Photoshop plugin for drawing flow charts

Tags: adobe-photoshop, diagram

I'm looking to add diagram functionality to Photoshop - specifically, the "sticky" functionality where if you draw two boxes and then connect them with a line, when you move a box, the line redraws itself to still connect the two boxes.

I know there are plenty of existing tools to create diagrams, from Visio to Gliffy - I'm not looking for a separate program. I already have a number of diagrams in Photoshop, and it's my preferred workspace for certain projects. My question is basically if I can make re-organizing a flow chart easier by adding the functionality of automatic line redrawing.

Does anyone know of such a plugin?

Comment: Why are you doing vector work in photoshop? I doubt there is one.

Comment: It's not necessarily vector - I might be drawing a line between two JPGs taken by a camera, for instance, and just want to connect them with a line. I just want to know if the functionality is there at all. And if not, do you know if that functionality exists for something like Illustrator?

Comment: @Jake, I'm sure you have a reason but you are mostly likely going to get comments like the above all day long.  You are better creating them in illustrator and bringing them into photoshop as a smart object if you need to do some additional work.  Perhaps even using another third party application for the flow charts and then just import a export into PS.

Comment: @Jake but the lines are vector if they're continuously rasterized. Also if you have multiple jpegs then a vector drawing software is better as you do not have the burden of keeping all pixels same size. I thought i saw something like this for illustrator years back. Personally I use yEd for layout though.

Comment: @Jake in that case you are better off bring those photos into Illustrator and creating your flow chart that way. AI is way more adapt for this purpose. I don't know of a plugin that will just be this drag and drop functionality but you can build up a library with symbols and do it that way.  The other way is to just use a dedicated 3rd party app or online solution. Just google it and bunch will show up. Lucidchart being one that comes to mind.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions - assuming I use AI though, the problem isn't so much the drag-and-drop of the symbols (I have a group of symbols already), but more of the automatic redrawing of the lines. In other words, I connect two boxes with a line and move one box, is there a way to get the line to move as well, without me having to move it manually? That would significantly speed up my workflow. I know there are plenty of other tools, Lucidchart and Gliffy, with that functionality - I'm looking to add it to an Adobe product, if possible (Either Photoshop or AI)